# Администрирование сервера

Tags: linux, сервер, ssh, ftp

Есть сервер на debian, владелец создал пользователя FTP и все файлы загружал через fileZilla. Есть данные для входа по ssh под root, я залогинился и к необходимой директории подключил репозиторий git. Всё, вроде бы работает, но создаются файлы от пользователя/группы - 0/0. Эти файлы нельзя редактировать по FTP, нет прав.
Насколько я понимаю, нужно по ssh зайти по тем же пользователем, что и на FTP, но как получить данные этого пользователя если он уже создан?

Comment: Спросить имя пользователя и пароль у человека, который загружает по FTP? Вообще вопрос больше похож на запрос в гугл. Вам поможет команда `chown` и, возможно, `passwd ftp_username`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я не сисадмин, просто вынужден этим заниматься, наверное вопрос сформулировал некорректно. Данные пользователя FTP у меня есть, но для ssh они не подойдут. Я читал, что можно сменить пароль пользователя, но я не знаю что тогда у него перестанет работать. В итоге мне нужно, что бы файлы загружаемые через git корректно работали на сервере, я так понимаю, для этого нужно авторизоваться под ним по ssh, но как это сделать не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала добавь `acl` к тому что с файлами сайта в fstab (у меня так)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information        VVV
UUID=04096adc-698d-495d-9381-cb4be0afcd9c / ext4 rw,acl,discard,errors=remount-ro,x-systemd.growfs 0 1
UUID=DC77-CE8E /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 0
```

Установи программу `acl` и перезагрузись

```
sudo apt install acl
```

Установи расширенные права для пользователя вэб-сервера(если это сайт) и пользователя фтп

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm g:www-data:rwX,u:ftpuser:rwX,u:www-data:rwX /var/www/
```

имя ползователя фтп можно посмотреть через `getfacl /var/www/его/загруженные/файлы`

И теперь файлы будут доступны без смены пользователя